# Is intermittent high ping an issue in my Macbook or my router?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, dns

Every 20-30 minutes, my internet seems to be unresponsive for about 10 seconds. I can easily see this if I'm running the `ping` command while it happens:

[image: pinging to 8.8.8.8, showing a good ping, followed by a sudden raise in ping time, then returning to the good ping]

Now, I have two routers on my network, both broadcasting the same network (with a different SSID).

I have this problem since a few months.

My `/etc/hosts` file only contains a few `127.0.0.1 mywebsite.dev` entries.

I'm using Yosemite.

So, is this an issue that must be resolved on my Macbook Air 2014 or on the router?

Comment: What is your Mac OS Version ? Are you using Chrome ?
I too had the same issue when I was using outdated version of Google Chrome ?

Comment: I use Yosemite. I don't use Chrome, I use Safari. Both browsers have the same problem though, so it's not the browser. Console doesn't show anything like that.

Comment: Do you have another device nearby which may send a signal disrupting WiFi every 30 minutes?

Comment: It happens everywhere in my house. Even in the back yard. All the same issue, nothing changes.

Comment: Try turning off Bluetooth and perform the test once again.

Comment: Do the pings to your router show the same slow down?  A long ping to google doesn't tell you whether the issue is internal or external to your home network.

Comment: I have the same problem and thought the issue was my cable modem. I changed modems and the same stuff is happening. I have a 2014 Macbook Air running Yosemite. I will randomly spike thousands in my ping. Today I looked at the ping while this was happening on my laptop and then looked at my desktop which was connected via ethernet cable. 23 ping on the desktop, 3000 on the Macbook Air. To be fair, I wasn't able to test the wifi ping of another device at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it turned out to be the router. It was an old 802.11g router that I replaced with a 5GHz 802.11n router. It works great now, no problems whatsoever.